# Como fazer para usar uma informação dinâmica vinda por ng-repeat {{}} e usá-la como argumento de uma função ng-click (botão)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, funções, ng-repeat

Tenho uma função `ng-click`:

```
ng-click = "adicionar(0);"
```

Esta função `ng-click` está dentro do laço `ng-repeat = "mercadoria in listademercadoria"`.

Existe uma maneira de passar uma informação de acordo com o *repeat* em que ela está contida?

Modo que estou tentando, sem sucesso:

```
ng-click = "adicionar({{mercadoria.mercadoria}});"
```

Segue código AngularJS:

```html
angular.module('meumodulo', [])

    .controller('mercadoriaCarrinho', function($rootScope, $http) {
            var ctrl = this;
            $rootScope.listademercadoria = [];
           
            $rootScope.mercadoria0 = {
                id: 'id1',
                setor: 'setor1',
                foto: 'foto1',
                descr: 'descr1',
                de: de1,
                por:por1,
                mercadoria: '0',
                quantidade: 1
            }

            $rootScope.listademercadoria.push($rootScope.mercadoria1);
            $rootScope.mercadoria1 = {
                id: 'id2',
                setor: 'setor2',
                foto: 'foto2',
                descr: 'descricao2',
                de: de2,
                por: por2,
                mercadoria: '1',
                quantidade: 1
            }
            
            $rootScope.adicionar = function (a){
     {
     $rootScope.listademercadoria[a].quantidade=$rootScope.listademercadoria[a].quantidade + 1;
     }      
    }
         
   });
```

Botão HTML que realizaria a ação de adicionar um à quantidade, na mercadoria com *index* em que está contido:

```
<button ng-click = "adicionar({{mercadoria.mercadoria}});"> + </button>
```

Ressalto que funções de outro tipo, de outros botões paralelos a este, estão funcionando corretamente, porém somente nesta função não estou conseguindo fazer com que funcione corretamente.

Comment: Seu index tem de ser estático? se não pode passar ele com adicionar($index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa do {{}}  basta retirar isso.

exemplo:

```
<div class="card" ng-click="goToListaDeRespostas($index)"  ng-repeat="item in lista | orderBy:'ordem'">
```

ou

```
<button ng-click = "adicionar(mercadoria.mercadoria)"> + </button>
```

Comment: OMG como não havia pensado nisso? MUITO obrigado CCastro!

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do CCastro está correta - entretanto acho que vale a pena uma explicação de quais casos precisam dos marcadores, e quais não:

- **Chaves duplas (`{{}}`)** são utilizadas para marcar uma expressão Angular. Você as utiliza quando deseja inserir conteúdo processado pelo Angular diretamente no HTML. Exemplo:
   `<div>{{conteudo}}</sdiv>`
- **Sem marcadores**: Quando você está utilizando a propriedade diretamente em um método exclusivo Angular: Exemplo:
   `<a href='#' ng-click="salvar(conteudo)">{{conteudo}}</sdiv>`
- **Chaves simples**: Quando você quer expressar um objeto javascript dentro de uma expressão nativa:
   `<a href='#' ng-click="salvar({valor: conteudo})">{{conteudo}}</sdiv>`